# How to access Documents directory to attach an e-mail or upload a .txt xamarin iOS

Tags: email, xamarin.ios

I already have programming time, but I'm new Xamarin iOS, I have an app that generates a .txt file and save it in the Documents directory, but I can not access my .txt to attach an e-mail or upload it to a page from the Web navigator.
  My question is. Is there any way to make this directory visible to attach my file to an email or to upload to a website?

I know I can save my .txt in iCloud and so is visible and could add to an email. And that's how I am currently doing, but I would not have to use iCloud

thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can access the documents folder using standard .Net APIs:

`var docsFolderPath = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.MyDocuments);`

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Probably I will not express well, I can create, delete, edit files. The problem is that I can not attach my file to an email that I can just explore the directory iCloud. I want to know if it is possible to make visible the "My Documenst" directory of my app when exploring the content of my iPad to add it to an email or upload from a web browser.

An apology for my English

Comment: You can add attachments to an email composed with `MFMailComposeViewController` and the `AddAttachmentData()` method.